# Chunking a WebM - what is the minimum size?

Tags: html5-video, webm, media-source

I'm chunking a WebM to load via Media Source Extensions.

```
const SEGMENT = 3
const chunks = Math.floor(duration/SEGMENT)
const chunk = Math.ceil(Math.max(1000000,size)/chunks)

if(chunks === 1 || size < 1000000)
    return [{from: 0, to: size}]

return [...Array(chunks -1).keys()].reduce((prev, next, index) => {

    if(index < chunks-2)
        return [...prev, {from: prev[index].to + 1, to: prev[index].to + chunk }]
    else 
        return [...prev, {from: prev[index].to + 1, to: size}]    

}, [{from: 0, to: chunk}])
```

This works 95% of the time, however, I've got some cases where the video fails to start with the error:

[image]

I'm assuming the important information isn't in the first MB as I've coded here.

What is the minimum chunk size so the video will play?

Comment: You'll probably need to divide on `Cluster` elements at a minimum.  https://www.matroska.org/technical/elements.html

Comment: Any idea how to get those cluster elements in Javascript?

Comment: Last time I needed to do that, I split the buffer on the cluster element type ID `0x1F43B675`.  So, every time you see that data, you can reasonably assume you have the beginning of a cluster.

Comment: Right and then only append that data to the buffer?